# Machine Learning - Support Vector Machines

Tags: machine-learning, svm

I came across an SVM example, but I didn't understand. I would appreciate it if somebody could explain how the prediction works. Please see the explanation below:

The dataset has **10,000 observations** with **5 attributes** (`Sepal Width`, `Sepal Length`, `Petal Width`, `Petal Length`, `Label`). The label gets `positive` if it belongs to the `I.setosa` class, and `negative` if belongs to some other class.

There are **6000 observations** for which the outcome is known (i.e. they belong to the `I.setosa` class, so they get positive for the label attribute). The labels for the remaining **4000** are unknown, so the label was assumed to be negative. The **6000 observations** and **2500** randomly selected observations from the remaining **4000** form the set for the **10-fold cross validation**. SVM (10 fold cross validation) is then used for machine learning on the **8500 observations** and the **ROC** is plotted.

Where are we predicting here? The set has **6000 observations** for which the values are already known. How did the remaining **2500** get negative labels? When SVM is used, some observations that are positive get negative prediction. The prediction didn't make any sense to me here. Why are those **1500 observations** excluded.

I hope my explanation is clear. Please let me know if I haven't explained anything clearly.

Comment: Why don't you post the source of the SVM analysis (the data set itself is classic, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iris_flower_data_set)

Comment: I didn't come across this example online. This is just an example that came up during a discussion on SVMs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the issue is a semantic one:  you refer to the set of 4000 samples as being both "unknown" and "negative"  -- which of these apply is the critical difference.

If the labels for the 4000 samples are truly unknown, then I'd do a 1-class SVM using the
6000 labelled samples [c.f. validation below].  And then the predictions would be generated by testing the  N=4000 set to assess whether or not they belong to the setosa class.

If instead, we have 6000 setosa, and 4000 (known) non-setosa, we could construct a binary 
classifier on the basis of this data [c.f. validation below], and then use it to predict setosa vs. non on 
any other available non-labelled data.

*Validation:* Usually as part of the model construction process you will take only a subset of your labelled
training data and use it to configure the model.  For the unused subset, you apply the model to the data (ignoring the labels), and compare what your model predicts against what the true labels are in order to assess error rates.  This applies both to the 1-class and
the 2-class situations above.

Summary: if all of your data are labelled, then usually one will still make predictions for a subset of them (ignoring the known labels) as part of the model validation process.

Comment: Thank you! Precisely answered what I was looking for, much appreciated Dave!

Answer (score 0):

Your SVM classifier is trained to tell if a new (unknown) instance is or not an instance of I. Setosa. In order words, you are predicting if the new, unlabeled instance is I.Setosa or not.

You found the incorrectly classified result, probably, because your training data has many more instances of the positive case than of the negative one. Also, it's common to have some error margin.

Summarizing: your SVM classifier learned how to identify I.Setosa instances, however, it was provided with too little examples of non-I.Setosa instances, which is likely to get you a biased model.